# Forwarding ref parameters through a ref struct with "unsafe" ref punning - is this safe?

Tags: c#, parameters, field, ref-struct

I am developing a C# incremental generator to act as a [wrapper between managed and unmanaged callbacks in a generic context](https://github.com/monkey0506/native-generic-delegates/tree/interceptors). That wrapper generates `interface`s that functionally work the same way as a `delegate`, with an `Invoke` method that supports up to 16 generic type parameters with or without a return type (named similarly to `System.Action` and `System.Func`).

I wanted to be able to add `ref`-qualified parameters to the `Invoke` method, but for the same reasons as `Action` and `Func`, there's simply no way to produce every permutation of `by-value`, `ref`, `in`, and `out` for 16 different parameters, even with a source generator. (*I'm elaborating on the end-goal to avoid an XY problem.*)

Considering alternative approaches, I arrived at the idea of using a `ref struct` with a `ref` field to represent any one of the possible `ref` "categories". I could use a normal field to store a "`by-value`" parameter (meaning *not `ref`-qualified*; not *necessarily* a `ValueType`), and a `readonly ref readonly` field to store a `ref`, `in`, or `out` parameter:

```
public enum RefCategory
{
    None = 0,
    Ref,
    InRef,
    OutRef
}

public readonly ref struct ParamProxy<T>
{
    [MaybeNull]
    private readonly T obj;
    private readonly ref readonly T _ref;

    public readonly RefCategory RefCategory;

    public static implicit operator ParamProxy<T>(T obj) => new(obj);
    [return: MaybeNull]
    public static implicit operator T(ParamProxy<T> proxy) => proxy.Value;

    public ParamProxy() : this(default!) { }

    public ParamProxy(T obj)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
        _ref = ref Unsafe.NullRef<T>();
        RefCategory = RefCategory.None;
    }

    public ParamProxy(ref T @ref)
    {
        Unsafe.SkipInit(out obj);
        _ref = ref @ref;
        RefCategory = RefCategory.Ref;
    }

    public ParamProxy(in T inRef, object? _ = null)
    {
        Unsafe.SkipInit(out obj);
        _ref = ref inRef;
        RefCategory = RefCategory.InRef;
    }

    public ParamProxy(out T outRef, int _ = 0)
    {
        Unsafe.SkipInit(out obj);
        Unsafe.SkipInit(out outRef);
        _ref = ref Unsafe.AsRef(in outRef);
        RefCategory = RefCategory.OutRef;
    }

    private readonly ref T GetRef(RefCategory category)
    {
        switch (category)
        {
            case RefCategory.None:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Parameter is not a by-ref parameter");
            case RefCategory.Ref:
                if (RefCategory != RefCategory.Ref)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Parameter is not a `ref` parameter");
                }
                break;
            case RefCategory.InRef:
                if ((RefCategory != RefCategory.InRef) && (RefCategory != RefCategory.Ref))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Parameter is not an `in` or `ref` parameter");
                }
                break;
            case RefCategory.OutRef:
                if ((RefCategory != RefCategory.OutRef) && (RefCategory != RefCategory.Ref))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Parameter is not an `out` or `ref` parameter");
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnreachableException();
        }
        return ref Unsafe.AsRef(in _ref);
    }

    public readonly ref readonly T InRef
    {
        get => ref GetRef(RefCategory.InRef);
    }

    public readonly ref T OutRef
    {
        get => ref GetRef(RefCategory.OutRef);
    }

    public readonly ref T Ref
    {
        get => ref GetRef(RefCategory.Ref);
    }

    [MaybeNull]
    public readonly T Value
    {
        get => RefCategory switch
        {
            RefCategory.None => obj,
            _ => Unsafe.IsNullRef(in _ref) ? default : _ref
        };
    }
}
```

This utilizes [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe) to avoid initializing the `obj` and/or `_ref` fields, based on the constructor used.

The `in` and `out` constructors have dummy parameters, because C# doesn't allow you to overload methods/constructors only by the `ref` category. However, with defaulted dummy parameters, the compiler is able to unambiguously resolve `new(ref x)`, `new(in x)`, and `new(out x)` from each other. (**Edit:** corrected constructor details)

This proxy type would allow my `interface`s to define `Invoke` like this:

```
public ParamProxy<TResult> Invoke(scoped ParamProxy<T1> t1, scoped ParamProxy<T2> t2, scoped ParamProxy<T3> t3);
```

My source generator is already analyzing type information (`T1`, `T2`, `T3`, `TResult`...), and I am able to reason about the types. I would similarly be able to inspect the invocations of `Invoke` and issue diagnostics at compile-time if the wrong `ref` category is used. Usability is not the concern in question.

My question here is whether I have done something **dangerous**. In particular, the `out` parameter requires using `Unsafe.AsRef` to avoid a "narrower escape scope" error.

The *specific context* of my use case leads me to believing that this is still a reliable and safe scenario:

- The `ref`, `in`, or `out` parameter is passed to the constructor of `ParamProxy<T>` (a `ref struct`)
- The `ParamProxy<T>` stores the `ref`-qualified parameter in a `ref` field
- The `ParamProxy<T>` object is passed to `Invoke` as a `scoped` parameter
- The `Invoke` method then "forwards" the `ref` field's value to an appropriate `ref`, `in`, or `out` parameter of a `delegate`
- The `delegate` is invoked immediately, before `Invoke` returns

The user code might then call `Invoke` like this:

```
var getIntValueFromNative = /* ...get interface instance... */;
getIntValueFromNative.Invoke(new(out int value));
```

Which would generate (via the source generator) an `Invoke` implementation that would do:

```
public void Invoke(scoped ParamProxy<int> param)
{
    handler(out param.OutRef); // `handler` is a `delegate`
}
```

Sorry for the lengthy post. I've tried to be thorough in describing the scenario. My early tests show the expected results. I'm leery of inadvertently leaking memory or corrupting the stack. Thank you in advance for any feedback!

Comment: Thinking on this, there is a vulnerability for `out` parameters where `new ParamProxy<T>(out T value)` is *not* directly passed into the `scoped` parameter. `value` would appear to the compiler as having been initialized, but it would not be. `ref` and `in` parameters would not have this issue, as they are already initialized before the proxy is constructed.

Comment: Not assigning a value to `outRef` before returning from the constructor breaks a language invariant, that `out` variables must be assigned before the method returns. Rather than doing `Unsafe.SkipInit(out outRef);`, I can do definite assignment of `outRef = default!;`. The proxy is *designed* to be passed into the `Invoke` method, but this definite assignment in the constructor protects against misuse.

Comment: It feels like you are over-engineering this. A better option might be to use dynamic code generation to generate the callback code and associated structs at runtime. Using delegates generated off those would avoid any ongoing reflection overhead.

Comment: By "dynamic code generation" are you talking about `System.Reflection.Emit` or using the `dynamic` keyword? When you say "generate the callback code at runtime" and "reflection overhead" it seems to suggest `S.R.E`. I'm explicitly avoiding that in order to support Native AOT.

Comment: The former. Yes AOT could be a problem there, I don't have experience with it.

Comment: FWIW, the first version of the project was implemented using `S.R.E`. I dynamically generated `class` types that inherited from `MulticastDelegate` and implemented the appropriate `interface`. This can't be done in normal code because delegates can only be declared using the `delegate` keyword. Unfortunately, Native AOT doesn't support `S.R.E` ([per Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net7%2Cwindows#limitations-of-native-aot-deployment)).

Comment: Using a source generator is definitely more work to achieve the same end-goal, and has different pre-requisites (I have to be able to read certain parameters at compile-time, which limits how the user can invoke those methods). I detailed what I'm doing here to try and decouple that from the actual question being asked. Adding `by-ref` parameters to my project is a new feature that I'm considering, and I wanted to make sure I understand things like `ref` fields and the `scoped` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I discovered [UnscopedRefAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.unscopedrefattribute), which lists `out` parameters as a use-case for the attribute. The article I cite below states that `out` parameters are implicitly `scoped`, and does not discuss `UnscopedRefAttribute`.

If I apply the attribute to the `out` parameter (constructor of the original question), then I can assign `_ref = ref outRef;`. No *tricky* usage of `Unsafe.AsRef` required to mask the escape scope error.

Additionally, trying to *intentionally* allow the `out` parameter to escape the `ParamProxy<T>.OutRef` gives an error. As best as I can tell, the compiler does correctly recognize that the stored `ref` field is a reference to the original `out` parameter. Even with the `UnscopedRefAttribute` applied, the compiler doesn't allow the `out` parameter to escape through the `ref` field in a way that the parameter itself couldn't be used.

---

I believe I have found my answer while reading more about the `scoped` keyword: [Low Level Struct Improvements - Change the behavior of out parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/low-level-struct-improvements#change-the-behavior-of-out-parameters).

While I'm still reasonably certain that in the *expected* use-case, the `out` parameter object wouldn't go out-of-scope, it's *conceivable* that someone could abuse this, which is why I had to use `Unsafe.AsRef` only in the `out` constructor.

What's more, is (per the link above), this usage is **explicitly disallowed** in the language (for `out` parameters). I may be getting the correct results now, but there's nothing to guarantee that future implementation changes in the runtime or language wouldn't cause this to break.

AFAICT, the `ref` and `in` constructors are valid, specifically *because* I did not make the constructor parameters `scoped`. If the parameters *were* `scoped`, then storing them in a `ref` field would violate their "escape scope".

The `out` constructor should be removed entirely, but the user can achieve the same effect by declaring and `default`-initializing a local and then passing it by `ref`. As far as the source generator is concerned, a `ref` is a valid argument for an `out` parameter, so this would still work.

```
var getIntValueFromNative = /* ...get interface instance... */;
int value = default;
getIntValueFromNative.Invoke(new(ref value)); // `value` is `out` parameter in `handler`
```

I still welcome any other feedback on this, but I'll mark this as the accepted answer.